# Como hacer una Consulta SQL que haga que todo los meses sean de 30 días

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta SQL, que haga el conteo de dos campos de fechas, la cuestión es que me están pidiendo que todos los meses se cuenten como si tuvieran todos 30 días.
He estado utilizando datediff para hacer el conteo de días, pero tengo el problema con eso de que todos los meses sean de 30 días, también he intentado agregar IF a la consulta pero no he podido realizar una consulta que funcione correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen muestro los dos campos de fechas, el campo cirrus es el conteo que debe haber en fechas y el campo DIAS es la consulta que he realizado y me arroja ese resultado

Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora

```
SELECT desde,hasta,cirrus, IF(datediff(hasta,desde)=30,30,IF(MONTH(desde)=2 AND day(hasta)>= 28,datediff(hasta,desde) +3 ,IF(MONTH(hasta) = 3 AND MONTH(desde) = 2 AND YEAR(desde) = 2020, datediff(hasta,desde)+2,IF(MONTH(hasta) = 3 AND MONTH(desde) = 2,datediff(hasta,desde)+3 ,IF(MONTH(desde)=1 AND MONTH(hasta)= 2,datediff(hasta,desde)+2, IF(MONTH(desde)=1 AND MONTH(hasta)= 3 AND YEAR(desde) = 2020 ,datediff(hasta,desde),IF(MONTH(desde)=12 AND MONTH(hasta)=2,datediff(hasta,desde)-1,IF(MONTH(hasta)=12 AND day(hasta)=31,datediff(hasta,desde),IF(MONTH(desde)=11 AND MONTH(hasta)=1,datediff(hasta,desde),IF(MONTH(desde)=1 AND MONTH(hasta)=3 AND DAY(hasta)<=27,datediff(hasta,desde)+1,datediff(hasta,desde)+1 )))))))))) AS DIAS FROM tmp
```

Estoy probando utilizar el CASE de la primer respuesta pero aun no logro que funcionen todas las fechas este es el código que voy

```
SELECT *,
 IF(month(desde) = month(hasta) AND diasmesuno = 30 AND diasmesdos = 30,
 diasmesdos,
    IF(month(desde) < month(hasta) AND year(desde) = year(hasta) AND (day(desde) - day(hasta) = 1),
       diasmesuno + day(hasta) + 1,
       IF(month(desde) < month(hasta) AND year(desde) = year(hasta) AND (day(hasta) - day(desde) = 1),
       diasmesuno + day(hasta) + 1,
          
          IF(month(desde) > month(hasta) AND year(hasta) = 2021 AND (day(hasta) - day(desde) = 1) and (month(desde) = 12),
       (diasmesuno + day(hasta) + 1) + ((month(hasta)-1) * 30) , 
             
               IF(month(desde) > month(hasta) AND year(hasta) = 2021 AND (day(desde) - day(hasta) = 1) AND (month(desde) = 12),
       (diasmesuno + day(hasta) + 1)  + ( ( month(hasta) - 1 ) * 30) , 
          
         
          
  
    IF(month(desde) = month(hasta) AND diasmesuno = 30  AND diasmesdos < 30 ,
    diasmesdos,
    IF(month(desde) = month(hasta),
    (diasmesdos - day(desde) + 1),
    IF(month(hasta) > month(desde) AND diasmesuno = 30 AND diasmesdos = 30,
       (((month(hasta) - month(desde)) = 2) * 30) + diasmesuno + diasmesdos,
           IF(month(hasta) > month(desde),
              (((month(hasta) - month(desde)) = 2) * 30) + diasmesuno + diasmesdos,
                IF(year(hasta) = 2021 AND (month(desde) < 12) AND (year(desde) = 2020)  AND diasmesdos = 30                   AND diasmesuno = 30,
                    ((12 - (month(desde))) * 30) + (month(hasta) * 30) + diasmesuno, 
               

           
      IF((year(hasta) = 2021) AND (year(desde) = 2020) AND (month(hasta) < 30) AND (month(desde) = 12),
        diasmesuno + day(hasta) + (( month(hasta)-1) * 30),
         
      IF((year(hasta) = 2021) AND (year(desde) = 2020) AND (month(hasta) < 30),
                 diasmesuno + day(hasta) + (( month(hasta)-1) * 30) + ((12 - month(desde)) * 30),
         
         
         IF(year(hasta) = 2021 AND (month(desde) < 12) AND (year(desde) = 2020)  AND diasmesdos = 30                   AND diasmesuno = 30,
                    ((12 - (month(desde))) * 30) + (month(hasta) * 30) + diasmesuno, 
                          
               IF(month(desde) < month(hasta) AND  year(hasta) = 2021 AND (day(desde) - day(hasta) = 1),
     ((12 - (month(desde))) * 30) + (month(hasta) * 30) + diasmesuno + 1,
   
       diasmesuno + diasmesdos)))))))))))))) as dias
FROM   (SELECT CASE 
                 WHEN Day(desde) < 
                      -- si es febrero el límite sería 28 o 29 
                      -- si es otro mes entonces 30 
                      ( CASE 
                          WHEN Month(desde) = 2 THEN (SELECT 
                          Day(Last_day(desde))) 
                          ELSE 30 
                        end ) THEN 
               -- si es día 1 incrementar límite a 31 para incluir el mes completo 
               CASE 
                 WHEN Day(desde) = 1 THEN 31 
                 ELSE 30 
               end - Day(desde) 
                 ELSE 30 
               end diasMesUno, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN Day(hasta) < 
                      -- si es febrero el límite sería 28 o 29 
                      -- si es otro mes entonces 30 
                      ( CASE 
                          WHEN Month(hasta) = 2 THEN (SELECT 
                          Day(Last_day(hasta))) 
                          ELSE 30 
                        end ) THEN Day(hasta) 
                 ELSE 30 
               end diasMesDos, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN ( Month(hasta) - Month(desde) ) - 1 > 0 THEN ( 
                 Month(hasta) - Month(desde) - 1 ) * 30 
                 ELSE 0 
               end AS diferenciaMeses,desde,hasta,cirrus
        FROM   tmp) AS fechas_30dias
```

[image]

El resultado esperado es el siguiente, en el campo cirrus sale los dias que la empresa necesita que sea el resultado, en el campo dias es el resultado de la consulta

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y ganar tu primera medalla. 
También podríás revisar [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.
Si para preguntas de BD, añades datos de prueba y resultados esperados, sería mucho más fácil saber qué esperas obtener.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu gran consejo voy a formular mejor mi pregunta muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

La función DateDiff existe para el caso complejo del calendario real. Si todos los meses son de 30 días, la aritmética es bien sencilla y puedes hacerla tu mismo.

La lógica sería algo como:

- Si ambas fechas están en el mismo mes, retornar la diferencia de días
- Si no sumar:

  - 30 - el día de inicio (que son los días transcurridos el primer mes)
  - más el día final (que son los días transcurridos del último mes). Tener en cuenta que si el día final es 31, se deben sumar solamente 30 días.
  - más el número de meses intermedios multiplicados por 30

Con una estructura y datos como estos:

```
CREATE TABLE fechas 
  ( 
     fecha1 DATE, 
     fecha2 DATE 
  ); 

INSERT INTO fechas VALUES ('2020-01-02', '2020-01-26'); 
INSERT INTO fechas VALUES ('2020-01-01', '2020-03-31'); 
INSERT INTO fechas VALUES ('2020-01-15', '2020-03-05'); 
INSERT INTO fechas VALUES ('2015-10-24', '2020-03-05'); 
INSERT INTO fechas VALUES ('2018-10-24', '2019-10-24'); 
INSERT INTO fechas VALUES ('2018-10-24', '2020-10-24'); 
INSERT INTO fechas VALUES ('2018-12-24', '2019-01-24');
```

Esta consulta:

```
select   *
       , case
           when Year(Fecha2) = Year(Fecha1) and Month(Fecha2) = Month(Fecha1) then Day(Fecha2) - Day(Fecha1)
           else 
                30 - day(fecha1) 
              + case
                  when day(fecha2) = 31 then 30
                  else day(fecha2)
                end
              /* cálculo de meses */
              + case 
                  when Year(Fecha2) = Year(Fecha1) then Month(Fecha2) - Month(Fecha1) - 1
                  else   12 - Month(Fecha1) 
                       + Month(Fecha2) - 1
                       + (Year(Fecha2) - Year(Fecha1) - 1) * 12
                end * 30
         end dias
  from fechas;
```

Devuelve los siguientes resultados

```
| fecha1     | fecha2     | dias |
| ---------- | ---------- | ---- |
| 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-26 | 24   |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-03-31 | 89   |
| 2020-01-15 | 2020-03-05 | 50   |
| 2015-10-24 | 2020-03-05 | 1571 |
| 2018-10-24 | 2019-10-24 | 360  |
| 2018-10-24 | 2020-10-24 | 720  |
| 2018-12-24 | 2019-01-24 | 30   |
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, estaba probando la consulta y funciona muy bien pero no esta dando el conteo de días que la empresa necesita, algunas fechas les falta un día por que ellos cuentan las fechas desde el el primer día y necesito también que  febrero lo coja como si tuviera 30 días, Realice una consulta con los CASE de la respuesta anterior pero hay unas fechas que tampoco me están dando bien

Comment: Sería de revisar, quizás quedó una pulga en la fórmula. ¿En qué caso puntual no está dando el resultado que esperas? ¿Cuál es la fecha inicio, la fecha fin, y el resultado esperado?

Comment: Es asi el resultado esperado. Fecha de Inicio: 2020-09-01 Fecha final:2020-12-31 ResultadoEsperado: 120,  Fecha de Inicio: 2021-01-01 Fecha final:2021-02-28 , ResultadoEsperado: 60, Fecha de Inicio: 2020-12-20 Fecha final:2020-12-31 , ResultadoEsperado: 11, Lo que se necesita es que se cuente también el día que inicio la fecha y que todos los meses sean tomados como de 30 días incluyendo febrero

Answer (score 1):

La consulta está dividida en dos partes, la primera es una consulta que calcula los días que faltan para llegar al día 30 en la fecha1 haciendo corrección para el mes de febrero, y calcula los días que van de la fecha2. También calcula los meses entre ambas fechas.

La segunda parte es una consulta superior que se encarga de sumar los días de la fecha1 más los días de la fecha2 y los días de los meses entre esas dos fechas. También evalúa el caso cuando ambas fechas están en el mismo mes.

```
CREATE TABLE fechas 
  ( 
     fecha1 DATE, 
     fecha2 DATE, 
     dias   INT 
  ); 

INSERT INTO fechas 
VALUES     ('2020-01-02', 
            '2020-01-26', 
            0); 

INSERT INTO fechas 
VALUES     ('2020-01-01', 
            '2020-03-31', 
            0); 

INSERT INTO fechas 
VALUES     ('2020-01-15', 
            '2020-03-05', 
            0); 

SELECT *, 
       CASE 
         WHEN diferenciameses = 0 THEN diasmesdos - ( 30 - diasmesuno ) 
         ELSE diasmesuno + diasmesdos 
       end AS dias 
FROM   (SELECT CASE 
                 WHEN Day(fecha1) < 
                      -- si es febrero el límite sería 28 o 29 
                      -- si es otro mes entonces 30 
                      ( CASE 
                          WHEN Month(fecha1) = 2 THEN (SELECT 
                          Day(Last_day(fecha1))) 
                          ELSE 30 
                        end ) THEN 
               -- si es día 1 incrementar límite a 31 para incluir el mes completo 
               CASE 
                 WHEN Day(fecha1) = 1 THEN 31 
                 ELSE 30 
               end - Day(fecha1) 
                 ELSE 30 
               end diasMesUno, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN Day(fecha2) < 
                      -- si es febrero el límite sería 28 o 29 
                      -- si es otro mes entonces 30 
                      ( CASE 
                          WHEN Month(fecha2) = 2 THEN (SELECT 
                          Day(Last_day(fecha2))) 
                          ELSE 30 
                        end ) THEN Day(fecha2) 
                 ELSE 30 
               end diasMesDos, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN ( Month(fecha2) - Month(fecha1) ) - 1 > 0 THEN ( 
                 Month(fecha2) - Month(fecha1) - 1 ) * 30 
                 ELSE 0 
               end AS diferenciaMeses 
        FROM   fechas) AS fechas_30dias
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu respuesta, estoy utilizando tu consulta, pero aun no logro que la consulta den el conteo de dias como lo necesitan la empresa, acabo de modificar la pregunta, para mostrar la consulta que realice con tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Si todos los meses son de 30 días únicamente habría que preocuparse por los meses que no, que exceptuando febrero tienen 31 y por lo tanto se les compensa restando un día, y a febrero se le compensa sumado dos, o uno cuando es bisiesto. Entonces, creando una vista (en memoria) de esas fechas y su respectivo número de días de compensación, para después contar cuántos días de compensación existen en cada intervalo de fechas.

```
SELECT f.desde
     , f.hasta
     , datediff(f.hasta,f.desde) dias
     , ( SELECT ifnull(sum(compensaciones.compensacion),0)
           FROM ( SELECT cast( concat_ws('-',a.anio, md.mes, md.dia) as date) fecha
                       , md.compensacion
                    FROM ( SELECT year(desde) anio FROM fechas
                           UNION
                           SELECT year(hasta) FROM fechas
                           GROUP BY 1
                         ) a
                      JOIN ( SELECT 01 mes, 31 dia, -1 compensacion UNION
                             SELECT 02, 28, +2 UNION
                             SELECT 02, 29, -1 UNION
                             SELECT 03, 31, -1 UNION
                             SELECT 05, 31, -1 UNION
                             SELECT 07, 31, -1 UNION
                             SELECT 08, 31, -1 UNION
                             SELECT 10, 31, -1 UNION
                             SELECT 12, 31, -1 
                           ) md
                ) compensaciones
           WHERE compensaciones.fecha between f.desde and f.hasta
       ) comp
     , ( SELECT dias+comp+1 ) cirrus  
  FROM fechas f;
```

Answer (score -1):

Primeramente comentarte que en tu programa, en el intervalo de fechas desde 2021-01-15 hasta 2021-03-05, cirrus devuelve 50 días y creo que deberían ser 51 (16 días de enero + 30 días de febrero + 5 días de marzo).
Te dejo mi código en sql para oracle por si te ayuda.

Saludos!

```
select (años - dias_ini - dias_fin + 1) total_dias

  from

   (select (extract (year from hasta) - extract (year from desde) + 1) * 12 * 30 años,

           (extract (month from desde) - 1) * 30
            +
           case 
              when (extract (day from desde) = 31) or
                   (extract (month from desde) = 2 and extract (day from desde) > 27)          
              then 30
              else extract (day from desde)
           end dias_ini,

           (12 - (extract (month from hasta)) + 1) * 30
            - 
           case
              when (extract (day from hasta) = 31) or
                   (extract (month from hasta) = 2 and extract (day from hasta) > 27)
              then 30
              else extract (day from hasta)
           end dias_fin

  from tabla_fechas

   )
```

tabla_fechas es una tabla con 2 campos, desde y hasta, de tipo DATE que contienen las fechas.